# Using Room in a library module

Tags: android, android-library, android-room

I am trying to migrate to Room and also refactor some of my code in libraries that I can include in different flavors.

I have created an entity and a Dao in my library, but I have doubts on how should I create/use the class that extends RoomDatabase, because I have another class that extends RoomDatabase in my "main" folder of the base app. I know I have to add the DAO to some class, but don't know if having another class that extends RoomDatabase will collide or if there's a better approach.

Comment: could you solve this problem?

Comment: no... I have stopped working on this for now

Comment: Looking forward to guidance on this topic too. If I get a solution, I will post here.